# Using Carousel without module

Tags: 7, javascript

I want to use jCarousel plugin or similar. But I do not want to use the module.

Add content will form part of and the carousel will add pictures. How can I do? Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You're going to end up essentially writing a watered-down version of the code from the jCarousel slideshow module anyway (no way around that) so why not just use it? Also please add more information to the question about what you want to achieve, what research you've done to solve the problem yourself, and most importantly [_what you've tried_](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). No-one's going to write a full module for you so you'll need to do your own research, and ask for help here on _specific issues_

Comment: @Clive ok, sorry. I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this on the theme level.

Your obviously going to want to setup the content using the CMS so will take the form of nodes.

You can then use a process function to determine what content type you are on for applying your script, for example...

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node($variables) {
   if ($SOME_NODE) {
      // Add JS plugin...
   }
}
```

You can then create template files for node or specific fields in that node with markup that the plugin can manipulate.

```
node--[CONTENT_TYPE].tpl.php
```

To be honest, take Clives advice, use the modules, thats what makes Drupal what it is.